# Convert an increasing number to a decreasing number within a range

Tags: python, list

I use a resistive tape to measure the level of water in my pool for my pool control system. I need to convert this value to a number representing a percentage value of how full my pool is in order to run my system.

My current method works, but I am trying to figure out a better way to do it. I did look at other methods of doing this, but my issue is that my resistive values are inverse to the converted number I am looking for and I was unable to make the math work.

For example a resistive value of 785 = 100, 786 = 99, 787 = 98, 788 = 97 and so on..

Here is what I currently have but I am certain there is a better way:

```
# Convert Pool Resistance reading to Percentage for web interface
def get_pool_level_percentage(level):
global pool_level_percentage
if level <= 785:
    pool_level_percentage = 100
elif level == 786:
    pool_level_percentage = 99
elif level == 787:
    pool_level_percentage = 97
elif level == 788:
    pool_level_percentage = 96
elif level == 789:
    pool_level_percentage = 95
elif level == 700:
    pool_level_percentage = 94
elif level == 791:
    pool_level_percentage = 93
elif level == 792:
    pool_level_percentage = 92
elif level == 793:
    pool_level_percentage = 91
elif level == 794:
    pool_level_percentage = 90
elif level == 795:
    pool_level_percentage = 89
elif level == 796:
    pool_level_percentage = 88
elif level == 797:
    pool_level_percentage = 87
elif level == 798:
    pool_level_percentage = 86
elif level == 799:
    pool_level_percentage = 85
elif level == 800:
    pool_level_percentage = 84
elif level == 801:
    pool_level_percentage = 83
elif level == 802:
    pool_level_percentage = 82
elif level == 803:
    pool_level_percentage = 81
elif level == 804:
    pool_level_percentage = 80
elif level == 805:
    pool_level_percentage = 79
elif level == 806:
    pool_level_percentage = 78
elif level == 807:
    pool_level_percentage = 77
elif level == 808:
    pool_level_percentage = 76
elif level == 809:
    pool_level_percentage = 75
elif level == 810:
    pool_level_percentage = 74
elif level == 811:
    pool_level_percentage = 73
elif level == 812:
    pool_level_percentage = 72
elif level == 813:
    pool_level_percentage = 71
elif level == 814:
    pool_level_percentage = 70
else:
    pool_level_percentage = 69
return pool_level_percentage
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your description, level 787 maps to 98% while in your code level 787 maps to 97%. Assuming that this is a typo and level 787 should map to 98%, 788 to 97% etc, the code below should do the trick. I also assume that `pool_level_perentage` can take values less than 69 (something which is not reflected in your code) so I won't include any further conditions.

```
def get_pool_level_percentage(level):

  if (level > 785):
    return (100 - (level - 785))

  return 100
```

Comment: Looks like it gives different result. Try `get_pool_level_percentage(810)`, it returns `75`

Comment: @0p3n5ourcE I think there is a typo in his code. He missed 98%.

Comment: Good observation! I hope it helps OP +1

Comment: Thank you, everyone, this is exactly what I was looking for....I was just making it way to complicated, this works exactly as requested and cleaned up a bunch of code!!